# iOS : How to build a bi-language iOS native application

Tags: ios, localization, nib

My customer want the iOS application that should have Bi-language(Arabic & English) support inside the application.I thought Localization will workout for this.But the design layout is different for arabic(RTL).How can i achieve this? Should design separate Nib file for both English & Arabic version.Please help me.